# Getting the Contacts from a Campaign in Siebel On Demand

Tags: oracle, crm, siebel

I am able to get a list of Campaigns and filter on those to get only the campaigns I want.

How do I get a list of Contacts for 1 specific campaign?

I have the web service classes in my project but can't see any way of relating to the Child objects of the Campaign object.

Documentation is awful, none of the examples had working code and they needed amending in order to work.

Comment: If you could post the schema of the involved tables it would help people answer the question.

Comment: Are you trying to extract this data using web services or using the inbuilt export functionality?

Comment: I'm using the web services from c# to try and get out the data. I've since found that Web Services 1.0 has the children as part of the object but Web Services 2.0 doesn't. 

I'd like to use 2.0 but don't know if it's going to be possible to do.

Comment: You may be able to query the contacts based on campagin in ws 2.0, but one of the features of ws 1.0 over 2.0 is getting back child records with parent records. WS 2.0 does not have this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is don't use v2 of the API - use v1 instead which means no strongly typed objects etc but it's the only way to do it